# Haskell - System.Process callCommand and other functions are not available

Tags: shell, haskell, io

While reading the docs of `System.Process` and trying to use `callCommand` I discovered that it is not available:

```
test.hs:1:24: Module `System.Process' does not export `callCommand'
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callProcess` was added to the [`process`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process) library in version `1.2.0.0`. I suspect you are using an earlier version.

Comment: How can I check it? I've just installed `haskell-platform` on a Debian system today (May 2nd, 2016), using `apt-get install haskell-platform`, shouldn't it be the newest??

Comment: @FtheBuilder Are you writing from the future? If I move my mouse over the "6 mins ago" text beside your name the date shown is today 2 **April** 2016.  Anyway I believe Debian *might* use a slightly outdated version of haskell-platform.

Comment: @Bakuriu I made  a mistake. Well, that is fine.